# GSA - how to ignore the session id from the url

Tags: url, sessionid, google-search-appliance, google-crawlers

Is it possible to configure the GSA to ignore the session_id from the indexed URL?
Because i'm having duplicated URLS with different sessions
[image: Same url indexed twice with different sessions]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add "dse_sessionId" to ‘Do Not Crawl URLs with the Following Patterns:’

More details here:
http://www.gsadeveloper.com/2006/04/20/avoiding-session-ids-when-spidering/